# How to seed a table with data from another table

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, orm

I made a simple website in ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework where you can manage employees. You have and Employee controller, those Employees belong to a specific department, and there are groups who are assigned to tasks and every kind of employee can be on it from every department.

Here is my seeding:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasData(
                new Employee() { Id = -99, Name = "Mary", Email = "mary@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 },
                new Employee() { Id = -98, Name = "Stan", Email = "stan@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 },
                new Employee() { Id = -97, Name = "Mike", Email = "mike@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
                .HasData(
                new Department() { DepartmentId = -99, Field = "IT", Name = "Programming Department" },
                new Department() { DepartmentId = -98, Field = "HR", Name = "Human Resorcues" },
                new Department() { DepartmentId = -97, Field = "AD", Name = "Advertisement Department" });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Group.Group>()
                .HasData(
                    new Group.Group() { GroupId = -1, Name = "Cleaner", Task = "Clean the building"}
                );
```

The thing is, I want that 1 group to have Employees in it, but I don't know how to seed those employees which are added before with Id -99,-98 and -97.

EDIT: Here I tried to make a list of my Employees and add them to the Employees field in Group:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var emp1 = new Employee() { Id = -99, Name = "Mary", Email = "mary@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 };
            var emp2 = new Employee() { Id = -98, Name = "Stan", Email = "stan@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 };
            var emp3 = new Employee() { Id = -97, Name = "Mike", Email = "mike@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 };

            List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>() { emp1, emp2, emp3 };
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasData(empList);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
                .HasData(
                new Department() { DepartmentId = -99, Field = "IT", Name = "Programming Department" },
                new Department() { DepartmentId = -98, Field = "HR", Name = "Human Resorcues" },
                new Department() { DepartmentId = -97, Field = "AD", Name = "Advertisement Department" });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Group.Group>()
                .HasData(
                    new Group.Group() { GroupId = -1, Name = "Cleaner", Task = "Clean the building", Employees = empList }
                );
        }
```

But I get this error:

The seed entity for entity type 'Group' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Employees' set. To seed relationships, you need to add the related entity seed to 'Employee' and specify the foreign key values {'GroupId'}. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the involved property values.

EDIT: Here is the seeding method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasData(
                new Employee() { Id = -99, Name = "Mary", Email = "mary@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 },
                new Employee() { Id = -98, Name = "Stan", Email = "stan@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 },
                new Employee() { Id = -97, Name = "Mike", Email = "mike@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
                .HasData(
                new Department() { DepartmentId = -99, Field = "IT", Name = "Programming Department" },
                new Department() { DepartmentId = -98, Field = "HR", Name = "Human Resorcues" },
                new Department() { DepartmentId = -97, Field = "AD", Name = "Advertisement Department" });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
                .HasMany(a => a.Employees);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
                .HasData(
                    new Group() { GroupId = -1, Name = "Cleaner", TodoId = -99 }
                );

            modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
                .HasMany(a => a.Employees);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Todo>()
                .HasData(
                    new Todo() { ProblemId = -99, Title = "Spilled drink in basement", Descrpition = "Someone spilled drink all over the place in the basement", IsDone = false, GroupId = -1 });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Todo>()
                .HasOne(a => a.Group);
        }
```

Here is my Group.cs :

```
public class Group
    {
        [Key]
        public int GroupId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int TodoId { get; set; }

        public Todo problem;

        public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();
    }
```

and my Employee.cs:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot exceed 50 characters")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_0+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Format")]
        [Display(Name = "Office Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }

        public int GroupId { get; set; }

        public Group Group { get; set; }
    }
```

The way I found out that nothing is in the Employees list is I logged out context.Employees.Count in the details function in the controller itself and it said 0

Comment: yeah im also struggling to understand your concerns/issue/problem, unsure what you trying to achieve... more words needed plz

Comment: Please edit your question showing *only* the seeding method you actually use, the class definitions and explicit mapping code (if any) and the method that determines that the property is empty. Then we can talk (and remove all our comments).

Comment: No time now. But try to append `WithOne` calls to the `HasMany` calls.